# MS Access query-String aggregation

Tags: ms-access

Looking for query in MS Access for below question-

Following is my data set where last row is with NULL in Value column. Also by doing Max(Value) for each Name+Office+Person+Category, I have extracted this data to avoid multiple rows with value

```
ID  Name    Office  Person  Category    Value
1   FMR    Americas Ben       Global    7
1   FMR    London   Ben       Global    5
1   FMR    London   Ben       Overall   4.2
156 Asset  London   Ben       Global    13
156 Asset   London  Ben       Overall   
157  WSR    Paris   Zen       Global      2
```

My Expected result set is as below- I am expecting cross mark or any indicator which will show that for ID,Name,Office,person combination has value for Global/Overll categories or not in single row. I know it's somewhat of similar to "String aggregation"

```
ID  Name    Office  Person  Global  Overall
1   FMR     Americas Ben      X 
1   FMR     London   Ben      X       X
156 Asset   London   Ben      X 
157  WSR    Paris    Zen      X
```

Appreciate your inputs..

Comment: i am was trying to do at front end but not working but so thought of to check query option

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this a little. I created two select queries Global and Overall

Global

SELECT ID, Name, Office, Person, Category AS Global
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE Category="Global" AND Value IS NOT NULL

Overall

SELECT ID, Name, Office, Person, Category AS Overall
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE Category="Overall" AND Value IS NOT NULL

Then I created a new query to join the select queries

SELECT g.ID, g.Name, g.Office, g.Person, Global, Overall
FROM Global g
LEFT JOIN Overall o ON g.ID = o.ID AND g.Name = o.Name AND g.Office = o.Office AND g.Person = o.Person

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing Value is Not Null.. i want such records and do not want to exclude and also not sure why name/office/person used in join

Comment: According to the final result you do not want to place an X in the column if the value is missing. When you remove that criteria an X would be placed in the Global and Overall columns for ID 156. In my query you need to join at least on ID and Office but included ID, Name, Office, and Person in case there were other data combinations in a larger set of data.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a list of unique id/name/office combinations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name, Office, Person
FROM TableName
```

Next, create subqueries for each category:
For Global:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Office, Person
FROM TableName
WHERE Category="Global"
```

For Overall:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Office, Person
FROM TableName
WHERE Category="Overall"
```

Finally, left join the subqueries to the main query, and use an expression to show the X:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name, Office, Person
    Iif(Global.ID Is Not Null, "X") AS IsGlobal,
    Iif(Overall.ID Is Not Null, "X") AS IsOverall
FROM (TableName
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Name, Office, Person
    FROM TableName
    WHERE Category="Global"
) AS Global 
ON TableName.ID=Global.ID
    AND TableName.Name=Global.Name
    AND TableName.Office=Global.Office
    AND TableName.Person=Global.Person)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Name, Office, Person
    FROM TableName
    WHERE Category="Overall"
) AS Overall
ON TableName.ID=Overall.ID
    AND TableName.Name=Overall.Name
    AND TableName.Office=Overall.Office
    AND TableName.Person=Overall.Person
```

It may be easier for you to save the subqueries as Access queries and reference the saved queries by name, instead of including the whole subquery in this query.